# Why doesn't my one-year-old son walk?

Tags: walking

My baby is turning one year old this week. He can stand up, balance, and walk a few steps. He can also walk using his push walker. Without the walker, he would rather crawl.

I don't know if this is because he is too lazy to walk or is this just a part of development.

Comment: It is perfectly normal. Some walk early, some late, but it usually doesn't affect overall development. I would be concerned if your child is around the 18 month mark and not taking steps, both my children were walking by 10 months but my nephew took until 16 months or so to walk.

Comment: @RonBeyer is correct and also crawling is a really good thing. Just let it happen!

Answer (score 3):

He doesn't walk yet because he's still gaining his balance.
It's normal. Any time before two years old is perfectly normal.

My eldest started at 20 months, and her sister at 12, and they're both fine.

The only advice any parent needs before the child is two is this: Relax, and let them get there in their own time. Then relax some more.

Answer (score 2):

Observing my own children, several nephews & nieces, I can say every child starts walking at different age. As suggested by others, usually it varies between 8 to 20 months.

Both my elder and younger son started walking 2 or 3 weeks after their first birthday. Two of my nephews started walking when they were 11 months old. One of my niece started walking when she was 8 month old.

Could be just my personal experience but I noticed girls start walking sooner than boys. Actually I heard this from several parents.